# Arbitrary line-ellipse intersection

Tags: calculus, geometry

I wish to find the solution to a line-ellipse intersection. This is to solve a problem where light is emitted (in every direction) from one point, hits a line, and is reflected (again in every direction) back to another point, the receiver. Hence at any moment in time, the possible positions of the light forms an ellipse where the emitter and receiver are the foci. If the line is parameterised as:

$(\mathbf{Y} + \lambda \mathbf{\hat{N}})$

where Y is a starting point, $\lambda$ is the point on the line $\in [0,Length]$ and $N$ is the direction vector, and then the ellipse is parameterised as:

$||E - P||_2 + ||R - P||_2 = ct$

where E and R are emitter and receiver positions (i.e the foci), P is any point on the ellipse, and ct is the length of the axes (i.e round-trip distance from emitter to ellipse to receiver).

Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccBcK.jpg

The general question is; **how best to determine which point on the line is reflecting at a certain round-trip time. I.e what is $\lambda(t)$?

Substituting the equation for the line into the ellipse equation as $P$, I have found the solution to be:

$\lambda(t) = \pm \bigg(\big[(-2 A B + 2 A c^2 t^2 + 2 A D + 2 B C + 2 c^2 C t^2 - 2 C D)^2 - 4 (-A^2 + 2 A C + 4 c^2 t^2 - C^2) (-B^2 + 2 B c^2 t^2 + 2 B D - c^4 t^4 + 2 c^2 D t^2 - D^2)\big]^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
+ 2 A B - 2 A c^2 t^2 - 2 A D - 2 B C - 2 c^2 C t^2 + 2 C D\bigg)/[2 (-A^2 + 2 A C + 4 c^2 t^2 - C^2)]$

where A, B, C and D are constant terms (dot products etc involving R and E).

This is correct, but unpleasant. It's fine for calculating the intersection point, but I then wish to use this in an integral over $t$:

$S[n] = \int_{\Delta n}^{\Delta (n+1)} \frac{1}{||\mathbf{E} - (\mathbf{Y} + \lambda(t) \mathbf{\hat{N}})||_2^2 \cdot ||\mathbf{R} - (\mathbf{Y} + \lambda(t) \mathbf{\hat{N}})||_2^2} dt
\label{eqls}$

To effectively discretize the light pulse into time bins and takes into account squared loss terms. However, when you replace $\lambda(t)$ with the solution above, it gets extremely complicated and I'm not able to find a closed form solution.

Is there a better approach to this?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m having a lot of trouble understanding what are the givens and what it is that you’re trying to solve for. How exactly is it that “the light forms an ellipse” when it’s following straight line segments on its way from emitter to receiver? Is the line fixed? Are $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf R$ fixed? If yes to both of those questions, then there’s only one possible point of reflection with associated unique transit time, and ellipses don’t enter into this at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the confusion. I'm assuming the light spreads circularly away from the source, and then circularly again from wherever it hits on the line. If you trace out the locus of the possible "positions of light" at a certain moment in time, i.e anywhere with the same roundtrip distance from E->A point->R, you get an ellipse. I want to effectively have the point on the line, $\lambda$, as a function of time, which is equivalent to solving this ellipse-line intersection problem.

E and R are indeed fixed.

Comment: Something there doesn’t sound right. For a given transit time between $E$ and $R$, the possible *reflection points* indeed lie on an ellipse, but for a fixed $E$, $R$ and line of reflection, there’s only one point on the line from which light can be reflected and reach $R$, so it doesn’t make sense to me to speak of that as a function of time. On the other hand, what I would think of as the possible “positions of light” at a given time is the wave front, which is the union of a pair of circular arcs. A diagram of what it is you’re trying to compute might clear things up for me and others.

Comment: I see where the confusion lies - I'll try to update with a diagram shortly.

"but for a fixed EE, RR and line of reflection, there’s only one point on the line from which light can be reflected and reach R". 

For a specific time this is correct, but overall every point on the line should reflect the light back towards R at some time (as for each point on the line it'll reflect the light circularly [technically semi-circularly but that's not of importance]).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iSFSrDp.jpg

Comment: All right. As I understand it, you’re basically taking a circular (spherical) wavefront that propagates at speed $c$ and continuously reradiating from the points at which that wavefront intersects the line.

Answer (score 0):

make the Ansatz $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ and $$y=mx+n$$

Comment: You forgot vertical lines, $x=c$.

Comment: then also $y=c$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using my parameterization the ellipse can take on any orientation/rotation, but with this method it cannot directly. Do you think it'd be value to have some kind of transformation to ensure the ellipse can be written in this form, then proceeding like that? I shall try it out, but just interested in any insight before I do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take the ellipse $$\left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 = 1$$

and intersect it with the line (slope is $\tan \psi$, and distance from origin $d$) $$ y \cos\psi -x \sin \psi = d$$

Parametrise the line with a distance $t$

$$ \pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{-d \sin \psi \\ d \cos \psi} + t \pmatrix{\cos \psi \\ \sin \psi} $$

which yields the following equation (to be solved for $t$)

$$ \begin{align} 
  A t^2 + B t + C &=0  \\
  A & = \frac{1}{b^2} -\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos^2 \psi}{a^2 b^2} \\
  B & = \frac{2 d (a^2-b^2)\cos \psi \sin \psi}{a^2 b^2} \\
  C & = \frac{d^2 (a^2-b^2)\cos^2 \psi}{a^2 b^2} + \frac{d^2}{a^2}-1
\end{align}$$

There are two solutions to be used in the parametrized line equation to get $(x,y)$.

$$ t = \begin{cases} -\frac{B}{2 A} - \sqrt{ \left(\frac{B}{2 A}\right)^2 - \frac{C}{A} } \\ -\frac{B}{2 A} + \sqrt{ \left(\frac{B}{2 A}\right)^2 - \frac{C}{A} }
\end{cases} $$